# How to build a native YouTube Player in C++ application?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, youtube

I would like to build a native YouTube Player in my Visual C++ application, like the one in iPhone.

Anyone has a hint ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have `ffdshow codecs` installed and then you can play flash videos([FLV](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flv/)) using [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454(VS.85).aspx).